# QR Code Scanner error in Android using ZXING library

Tags: android, zxing

I have the following code. Whenever I press a button, the result is displayed in Display class but sometimes it throws me out from app and sometimes it works properly. I Dont know how?

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context con = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onScanClick(View view) {
            initiateScan();
    }

    private void initiateScan() {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator((Activity) con);
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
        integrator.initiateScan();
    }

    // Get the results:
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            if(result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                ShowResult.Dispay((Activity) con,result.getContents());
                Vibrator.vibrate(250L,con);
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error in the log?

Comment: @MichaelStoddart: No

Comment: Are you SUUURE there is no error in the log? Are you monitoring the memory?

Comment: Ya, I am sure.yup